# Convert array with 3-element rows into hierarchical array with 3 levels

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, grouping, hierarchical-data

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[98] => Array
(
    [City] => Caracas
    [Country] => Venezuela
    [Continent] => Latin America
)

[99] => Array
(
    [City] => Cairo
    [Country] => Egypt
    [Continent] => Middle East
)

[105] => Array
(
    [City] => Abu Dhabi
    [Country] => United Arab Emirates
    [Continent] => Middle East
)

[106] => Array
(
    [City] => Dubai
    [Country] => United Arab Emirates
    [Continent] => Middle East
)

[107] => Array
(
    [City] => Montreal
    [Country] => Canada
    [Continent] => North America
)
```

I am trying to group this array into a new multi-dimensional array structure, so that it outputs something like:

```
Continent
    - Country Name    
      -- Cities under Every Country
```

Exact desired result:

```
array (
  'Latin America' => 
  array (
    'Venezuela' => 
    array (
      0 => 'Caracas',
    ),
  ),
  'Middle East' => 
  array (
    'Egypt' => 
    array (
      0 => 'Cairo',
    ),
    'United Arab Emirates' => 
    array (
      0 => 'Abu Dhabi',
      1 => 'Dubai',
    ),
  ),
  'North America' => 
  array (
    'Canada' => 
    array (
      0 => 'Montreal',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how is the array being generated?

Comment: I have a SQL query that returns the array.

Comment: Maybe it's much easier to organize data by SQL grouping.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$array = array(
    98 => array(
        'City' => 'Caracas',
        'Country' => 'Venezuela',
        'Continent' => 'Latin America',
    ),
    99 => array(
        'City' => 'Cairo',
        'Country' => 'Egypt',
        'Continent' => 'Middle East',
    ),
    105 => array(
        'City' => 'Abu Dhabi',
        'Country' => 'United Arab Emirates',
        'Continent' => 'Middle East',
    ),
    106 => array(
        'City' => 'Dubai',
        'Country' => 'United Arab Emirates',
        'Continent' => 'Middle East',
    ),
    107 => array(
        'City' => 'Montreal',
        'Country' => 'Canada',
        'Continent' => 'North America',
    )
);

$newArray = array();
foreach ($array as $row)
{
   $newArray[$row['Continent']][$row['Country']][] = $row['City'];
}

print_r($newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple more alternative approaches:

Use "array destructuring" in a body-less `foreach()` to populate the hierarchical structure ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Z6bUe)) ([Further about the technique](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71807960/2943403))

```
$result = [];
foreach (
    $array as
    [
        'Continent' => $a,
        'Country' => $b,
        'City' => $result[$a][$b][]
    ]
);
var_export($result);
```

---

Use `array_reduce()` to avoid declaring a result variable in the global scope. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/d7n8V))

```
var_export(
    array_reduce(
        $array,
        function($result, $row) {
            $result[$row['Continent']][$row['Country']][] = $row['City'];
            return $result;
        }
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution:

```
function arrayToMultiDimensionalArray(array $elements, array $dimensions)
{
    $output = [];

    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $outputElement =& $output;

        // Foreach to build up the dimensions
        foreach ($dimensions as $dimension) {
            $outputElement =& $outputElement[$element[$dimension]];
        }

        $outputElement[] = $element['City'];
    }

    return $output;
}

$dimensions = ['Continent', 'Country'];

$tree = arrayToMultiDimensionalArray($array, $dimensions);
```

Comment: @mickmackusa Just change 
$outputElement[] = $element;
to
$outputElement[] = $element['City'];
problem solved

Comment: @mickmackusa A "thank you" would be nice.

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't do "thank you"s.  Just the same, you can thank me for bringing to your attention that your answer wasn't (and still isn't) the best version of itself.  I know what your script is doing, but there will be many PHP developers who won't and they might not use it because they don't understand how it works.

Answer (score -1):

I think you just need to loop in your array and create a new one using some values as keys and some other as value, for example

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $val)
{ 
     $new_array[$val['Continent']][$val['Country']] = array('City' => $val['City']);
}
```

[Live Sample](http://codepad.viper-7.com/tOQ8lz)

Comment: This answer is incorrect because it only allows one city per subset. Proof: https://3v4l.org/aDqFQ