# How to group same value elements in a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my object and I want to create a menu from the submenu in it.

I am working on a project that needs to categorize the menu list groups by their parent name.

```
[
    {
        "parent": "Assessment",
        "name": "Assessment Due date"
    },
    {
        "parent": "Assessment",
        "name": "Grading Schemes"
    },
    {
        "parent": "Registration",
        "name": "Manual Grouping"
    }
]
```

I have tried the Javascript code below

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(document).on('change','#parentMenu', function () {
        console.log("It has changed");
        var ParentMenuId = $(this).val();
        // console.log(ParentMenuId);
        $.ajax({
            type:'get',
            url: '{!! URL::route('submenu') !!}',
            data: { 'id': ParentMenuId },
            dataType:'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#submenulist").empty();
                data.forEach(function (element) {
                    $("#submenulist").append('<li><a href="#">'+ element.name +'</a></li>');
                })
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I am getting the list of the items like this

```html
<li>Assessment Due date</li>
<li>Grading Schemes<li>
<li>Manual Grouping<li>
```

but I want to group it by the parent so I want to produce this

```html
<ul>Assessment<\ul>
<li>-Assessment Due date</li>
<li>-Grading Schemes</li>
<ul>Registration</ul>
<li>-Manual Grouping</li>
```

Please, any one to assist me get the menu in the form of parent and children.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a Single Array into a multidimensional array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911822/how-to-convert-a-single-array-into-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: Is this code in php ? Please check your syntax and please edit your question

Comment: for starters, check your desired html structure.  `<ol>` is supposed to **wrap** the `<li>`s, not precede them.  e.g. `<ol><li>item1</li><li>item 2</li></ol>`

Comment: Ok thanks. I have edited the question. Can you help me out with the solution?

Comment: @CaddyDZ can you assist me?

Comment: @VaheGalstyan Any help?

Comment: @Erich I have modified the code, any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to group your data by `parent`:

```js
const data = [
    {
        "parent": "Assessment",
        "name": "Assessment Due date"
    },
    {
        "parent": "Assessment",
        "name": "Grading Schemes"
    },
    {
        "parent": "Registration",
        "name": "Manual Grouping"
    }
];

const groupedData = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  (acc[curr.parent] = acc[curr.parent] || []).push(curr);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(groupedData);
```

Then you can the use `groupedData` to produce the menu in the way you want. If you need, you can get the parent names from `groupedData` by calling `Object.keys(groupedData)`. With this, you can decide the order of the parents you want to display. You could sort them alphabetically, for example.